# UC_IMAGE_PATH Update Tool problem

Tags: java, glassfish-3

I downloaded and installed Glassfish 3 on my 32bit Windows XP Pro machine.

I try to run the "Update Center" and get an error that UC_IMAGE_PATH is not set. I can set this, but to what value? Googling hasn't found anything yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what happens is this:
During installation, Glassfish checks to see whether you already have Python installed.
If not, then it creates a directory, python2.4-minimal, in C:\glassfish3\pkg (or wherever you're installing Glassfish).
But if you have python already, then it doesn't create this directory.
However, when you then try to start the Update Tool, it looks in C:\glassfish3\pkg\python2.4-minimal for something, and when it can't find that directory, it falls down.
Setting the environment variable to the location of your Python installation doesn't seem to work.
Eventually, I gave up on that, and just **uninstalled Glassfish and Python, then reinstalled Glassfish**.
Now Update Tool starts up fine.
I guess I can reinstall Python, too, but I haven't done so yet.
Hope this works for you - it would be better if I'd somehow got the the environment variable to work, though.

Comment: Yeah I ended up reinstalling. Quite disappointing that such action was needed.